# How to Email report generated by Html-test runner (.html) to specific user using gmail account?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I have learned how to generate test reports(.html format) in python.Now I'm planning to send the generated report through email.
I'm using the following code but unable to do so:

```
if __name__=='__main__':
    unittest.main(testRunner=HtmlTestRunner.HTMLTestRunner(output='Dmat_dir',filename="Test_report"))


fromaddr="xyz@gmail.com"
    toaddr="cda@gmail.com"


msg = MIMEMultipart()
msg['From']=fromaddr
msg['TO']=toaddr
msg['Subject']="Test_Report"
body=" "
msg.attach(MIMEText(body,'plain'))
filename="Test_Report"


part=MIMEBase('application','octet-stream')
part.set_payload((attachment).read())
encoders.encode_base64()
part.add_header('Contnent -Disposition',"attachment; filename =%s"%filename)
msg.attach(part)
server=smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com',587)
server.starttls()
server.login(fromaddr,"login1")
text = msg.as_string()
server.sendmail(fromaddr,toaddr,text)
server.quit
```

There is a further query to it that the file name is generated randomly

how to make the code to send the latest test report?

Comment: What is your issue? Does code throw an exception?

Comment: The code is not allowing me to choose my defined file name.
C:\Users\inswadhwa\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\python.exe C:/Users/inswadhwa/PycharmProjects/automation/assertion.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/inswadhwa/PycharmProjects/automation/assertion.py", line 112, in <module>
    unittest.main(testRunner=HtmlTestRunner.HTMLTestRunner(output='Dmat_dir',filename ="Test_Report"))
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'filename'

Answer (score 0):

I have found one article which help you with same :-

http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/send-mail-gmail-account-using-python/

Also,you need to change setting of gmail account you are using. Also you need to grand some permissions. Like pop setting etc

https://support.google.com/mail/answer/7104828?hl=en

Hope it will help you

Comment: Hey Shubham this links didn't help to send an attachment...
 Let me reframe it to be more clear I have generated a test report in .html format now i want to send that html report to particular person.
hope this makes more sense

Comment: The link I have provided have a line as s.sendmail("sender_email_id", "receiver_email_id", message)

Comment: sender is your id and receiver is email id of a person whom to you want to send email. As an real world scenario you require a sender who will send the mail and a receiver who receive email

Comment: Now you just need to attach your html along with this email

Comment: The code is not allowing me to choose my defined file name. C:\Users\inswadhwa\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32‌​\python.exe C:/Users/inswadhwa/PycharmProjects/automation/assertion.py Traceback (most recent call last): File "C:/Users/inswadhwa/PycharmProjects/automation/assertion.py"‌​, line 112, in <module> unittest.main(testRunner=HtmlTestRunner.HTMLTestRunner(outpu‌​t='Dmat_dir',filenam‌​e ="Test_Report")) TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'filename'